# Displayed lists by JS

Tags: javascript, html, list, tags

I want to see three different lists depending on which one I choose. The problem is that when I want to display the second one, the first one does not disappear (I used remove() ). May someone help? And the second question is, is there an easier way to create **li** in **ul** with JS? My code is overcomplicate  I guess. *I'm beginner with JS btw.

```
function showList()
    {
        var games = document.getElementById("games").checked; // true;false
        var movies = document.getElementById("movies").checked; // true;false
        var series = document.getElementById("series").checked; // true;false

        if(games == true)
        {
            var exists = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
            if (exists == true)
            {
                exists.remove();
            }

            var ul = document.createElement('ul');
            var li = document.createElement("LI");
            var content1 = document.createTextNode("Witcher");
            li.appendChild(content1);
            ul.appendChild(li);
            document.getElementById('box_list').appendChild(ul);

            var li2 = document.createElement("LI");
            var content2 = document.createTextNode("GTA V");
            li2.appendChild(content2);
            ul.appendChild(li2);
            document.getElementById('box_list').appendChild(ul);
        }
        if(movies == true)
        {
            var exists = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
            if (exists == true)
            {
                exists.remove();
            }

            var ul = document.createElement('ul');
            var li = document.createElement("LI");
            var content1 = document.createTextNode("Matrix");
            li.appendChild(content1);
            ul.appendChild(li);
            document.getElementById('box_list').appendChild(ul);

            var li2 = document.createElement("LI");
            var content2 = document.createTextNode("The Lord of The Rings");
            li2.appendChild(content2);
            ul.appendChild(li2);
            document.getElementById('box_list').appendChild(ul);
        }
        if(series == true)
        {
            var exists = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
            if (exists == true)
            {
                exists.remove();
            }

            var ul = document.createElement('ul');
            var li = document.createElement("LI");
            var content1 = document.createTextNode("Game of Throne");
            li.appendChild(content1);
            ul.appendChild(li);
            document.getElementById('box_list').appendChild(ul);

            var li2 = document.createElement("LI");
            var content2 = document.createTextNode("The Walking Dead");
            li2.appendChild(content2);
            ul.appendChild(li2);
            document.getElementById('box_list').appendChild(ul);
        }

    }
```

---

```
<input type="radio" name="list" id="games" onclick="showList()"/> Game <br/>
<input type="radio" name="list" id="movies" onclick="showList()"/> Movies <br/>
<input type="radio" name="list" id="series" onclick="showList()"/> Series <br/>

<p id="box_list">

</p>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_remove.asp refer this to check how remove works

Comment: var elem = document.getElementById("myDiv");
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem); this is javascript way of doing same

Comment: You can also check this approach mentioned here in this question if you have option of using javascript
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58347346/how-to-hide-previous-button-only-on-first-page-div-and-hide-next-button-on/58347758#58347758

Answer (score 1):

your code is a bit messy. Try to use functions with few lines, they will be more readable. Also try to avoid the `onclick` event inside HTML because it's a bad practice (check online why). Finally **use variables** instead of calling `document` every time. For your problem I created this solution:

```js
var games = document.getElementById('games');
var movies = document.getElementById('movies');
var series = document.getElementById('series');
var boxList = document.getElementById('box_list');

games.addEventListener('click', () => addToList('a','b'));
movies.addEventListener('click', () => addToList('c','d'));
series.addEventListener('click', () => addToList('e','f'));
    
function addToList(...names){
         let ul = document.createElement('ul');
         for(let name of names){
            let li = document.createElement("li");
            let content = document.createTextNode(name);
            li.appendChild(content);
            ul.appendChild(li);
         }
         boxList.innerHTML = '';
  boxList.appendChild(ul);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="list" id="games" /> Game <br/>
<input type="radio" name="list" id="movies"/> Movies <br/>
<input type="radio" name="list" id="series"/> Series <br/>

<p id="box_list">
</p>
```

If you are unfamiliar with javascript, the `...names` is called spread operator and it's useful when you have to cycle a list of object (in this case some strings)

Comment: It's more of advanced record, I admit it's shorter but I'd have to analyse it a bit longer to full understand it. Anyway, appreciate for answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I did some edit, you can use this as an html file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="radio" name="list" id="games" onclick="showList()" /> Game
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="list" id="movies" onclick="showList()" /> Movies
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="list" id="series" onclick="showList()" /> Series
    <br />

    <p id="box_list"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function showList() {
        var games = document.getElementById("games").checked; // true;false
        var movies = document.getElementById("movies").checked; // true;false
        var series = document.getElementById("series").checked; // true;false

        if (games == true) {
          var elem = document.querySelector("ul");
          elem && elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);

          var ul = document.createElement("ul");
          var li = document.createElement("LI");
         
          li.innerHTML = "Witcher";
          ul.appendChild(li);
          document.getElementById("box_list").appendChild(ul);

          var li2 = document.createElement("LI");
          li2.innerHTML = "GTA V";
          ul.appendChild(li2);
          document.getElementById("box_list").appendChild(ul);
        }
        if (movies == true) {
          var elem = document.querySelector("ul");
          elem && elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);

          var ul = document.createElement("ul");
          var li = document.createElement("LI");

          li.innerHTML = "Matrix";
          ul.appendChild(li);
          document.getElementById("box_list").appendChild(ul);

          var li2 = document.createElement("LI");
          li2.innerHTML = "The Lord of The Rings";
          ul.appendChild(li2);
          document.getElementById("box_list").appendChild(ul);
        }
        if (series == true) {
          var elem = document.querySelector("ul");
          elem && elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);

          var ul = document.createElement("ul");
          var li = document.createElement("LI");

          li.innerHTML = "Game of Throne";
          ul.appendChild(li);
          document.getElementById("box_list").appendChild(ul);

          var li2 = document.createElement("LI");
          li2.innerHTML = "The Walking Dead";
          ul.appendChild(li2);
          document.getElementById("box_list").appendChild(ul);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I'm gonna analyse that :)

Comment: elem && elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem); -> Could you explain me that line? I mean, i don't know this kinda record. I usually use && in If() and the second thing, why it's not enough to write only "elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem)" to work this script?

Comment: if elem is null elem.parentNode.removeChild() gives error, we could do with `if (elem) {elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);}` but i prefer elem && .., interpreter interprets from left to right, in this example `a && b` if a is null or zero or empty string, interpreter doesn't proceed to right of expression.